# a matrix math code error

Tags: java, arrays, math

i am trying to write a code that would perform matrix multiplication by myself for exercise. right now, i had high hopes that the following would do the job, - there are no syntax errors, according to blueJ!- but when i try running it it says that there is an error, as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class matrix{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter n' of lines and columns in A");
        int linesA = scan.nextInt();
        int columnsA = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter n' of lines and columns in B");
        int linesB = scan.nextInt();
        int columnsB = scan.nextInt();
        // NOW WE HAVE LINES & COLUMNS OF A AND B

        if (columnsA == linesB)
            System.out.println("please enter A, line by line");
        else
            System.out.println("please enter valid information");

        int Axx = columnsA * linesA; // now we have the number of degits in A
        int[] Aln = new int[Axx];// now we created the array that would hold A
        int i = 0;// only to count to input of all A
        while (i < Axx) {
            Aln[i] = scan.nextInt();// inputs of A
            i++;
        }// now we have all degits of A

        int Bxx = columnsB * linesB;
        int[] Bln = new int[Bxx];
        System.out.println("please enter B , line by line");
        i = 0;// only to count to input of all B
        while (i < Bxx) {
            Bln[i] = scan.nextInt();// inputs of B
            i++;
        }// now we have all degits of B
        int sizeTarget = linesA * columnsB;
        int[] target = new int[sizeTarget];
        i = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        while (i < sizeTarget) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (i < columnsA) {
                sum += (Aln[a]) * (Bln[b]);
                a++;
                b += columnsB;
                target[i] = sum;
            }
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(target));

    }
}
```

and then it says that there is an "out of bounds array index" in the line

```
      sum+= (Aln[a])*(Bln[b]
```

Comment: Someone will have to trace (with paper and pencil) your code's execution for a small case, such as both A and B being 2x2, to figure out where and how the program steps outside the bounds of one of those arrays.  That someone ought to be you.

Comment: i tried that, couldn't figure out whats going on...

Comment: Run your program in debug mode or add syso statements to figure out.

Comment: it means that some how a or b are getting values that are bigger than the array was defined at the beginning?

Comment: Can you remove that `Scanner` and provide a [mcve] please... I suspect your logic with the increment of `b` is incorrect...

Comment: Have you verified the size of your arrays? To me it looks like declaring `Bln` and `Aln` Should be fine, but that `sizeTarget` is larger than one of your arrays. Are your matrices different sizes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that in your nested while loop, you only increment i on the outer loop. In the inner loop "i" stays the same but "a" increments. So your inner loop will keep on running forever since you only check it against "i" and you never increment "i". "a" will keep on increment until it is out of the bound of your array, resulting in your error.

Comment: sure, but it says something a bit offensive-claiming that my vote is not important enough to be recorded as i am too new here.. did what i can,anyway